# What is a quick strategy to call a method on every element of a list in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

So i want to grab some Model objects for the template view, but i need to call a compute hotness or a compute ranking on every selected element prior.

```
models = Model.objects.a_bunch_of_filtering_sorting()
```

So what is a fast way to do this?
Maybe reiterating the list?

```
for model in models: # Surely it can't be this
   model.the_method()
```

I tried to do some custom SQL stuff, but it won't allow any method calls or the list is sorted too early

```
sortValue = ORDER BY ....
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
SELECT d.field1, d.field2 ........ 
# unfortunately method calls aren't allowed in here

FROM Model_model d
GROUP BY 1
%s""" % sortValue)

for row in cursor.fetchall():
d = self.model(id=row[0] .... )
d.the_method() # wont work, the list is already 
               # ordered so we are calculating a sorting key one step behind
```

So what are the possible steps I can take to call a method on all of my django models (the most preferred way), before sorting them and releasing them into the template

Thanks

Comment: Really, the for loop isn't so bad.

Comment: I havent tried it ... but since it returns class instances couldnt you overload `__init__` ?

Comment: sorry, i'm really new to django and web frameworks in general, so this type of double loop is considered ok?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
for model in models:
   model.the_method()
```

you can try this

```
from itertools import imap
from collections import deque
from operator import methodcaller
deque(imap(methodcaller('the_method'), models), maxlen=0)
```

but it usually won't be any/much faster, and is certainly not clearer

Answer (score 0):

If method `the_method` does new SQL, and if number of models is big, then it could really harm performance, because of additional query for each object. In this case it'd be good to do only one SQL that'll update all needed objects. If `the_method` doesn't execute new query, it's perfectly fine to use loop - they're made exactly for this purpose.